# Destructuring objects inside an array inside an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "abc",
    body: "lorem ipsum",
  },
  {},
]
```

And I want to access the innermost keys of this tree (`id`, `title`, `body`) via ES6 destructuring. Currently, am able to achieve this in three stages:

```
const { posts } = data;
const [post] = posts;
const {title, body} = post;
```

But I'm wondering if it's possible to do so in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

```js
posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "abc",
    body: "lorem ipsum",
  },
  {},
];

const [{ id, title, body: newBody }] = posts
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the work for the first item:

```
let [{id, title, body}] = posts;
```

For loops:

```
posts.map(({id, title, body}) => { /* ... */})
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get all `id`s without using map?

Comment: Well, you need some form of loop to go through the objects. I think the form `const ids = posts.map(({id}) => id)` is the easiest, most readable form, but you can also choose a `for`-loop. So no, there's no way to do this without loops or array-functions (`Array.map`, `Array.forEach`, `Àrray.reduce` and others).

Answer (score 1):

Just put `posts[0]` on the right:

```js
posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "abc",
    body: "lorem ipsum",
  },
  {},
];
const { title, body } = posts[0];

console.log(title, body);
```

You can also put the `[]`s on the left, around the `{}`, but it's not so readable:

```js
posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "abc",
    body: "lorem ipsum",
  },
  {},
];
const [{ title, body }] = posts;

console.log(title, body);
```